# Is this a reasonable implementation of a cancelable Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, reactivex

I have a multi-step process - a callback-taking function, and two promise-returning functions - and I'd like to construct an Observable around it that supports being canceled. What I've got is:

```
let observableFromEvent = evt => Observable.create(({ next, error, complete }) => {
    let canceled
    Promisify(callbackFn)(evt)
       .then(r => !canceled && promiseF1(r))
       .then(r => !canceled && promiseF2(r))
       .then(next)
       .then(complete, error)
    return () => {
        canceled = true
    }
})
```

Can anyone tell me if I've left anything out? Or left too much in?
My intended usage is:

```
event$.switchMap(observableFromEvent)
```

to create a series of Observables which cancel their previous when they are spawned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with builtin operators, as simple as following:

```
observableFromEvent = evt => Observable
  .bindCallback(callbackFn)(evt)
  .flatMap(promiseF1)
  .flatMap(promiseF2)
```

Comment: That's great- it's inherently cancelable? I will try soon!

Comment: What makes this cancelable inherently cancelable?

Comment: Yes, it is inherently cancelable - that's a beauty of rxjs. Each operator creates new observable which is cancelable on its own, and will unsubscribe from underlying observables when you unsubscribe from it. So if you for example unsubscribe from it before `promiseF1` emitted a value - `promiseF2` would not be called.

Comment: Very helpful, @bogdan. I did an interactive illustration of it at runkit: https://runkit.com/deanius/58f4243c4ddb1a00124c7069